# Django admin и предзаполнение полей в списке объектов

Tags: django, django-admin

Имеется Django 4.0 python 3.10.

В моделях есть интовое поле "Show Average" с дефолтным значением = 0, и есть калькулятор расчитывающий это поле для каждого объекта в БД. Задача такая: в админке, при просмотре таблицы всех объектов, пересчитать и переписать значения этого поля у всех объектов.

[image: Пример]

Уменя получилось реализовать задуманное через *def formfield_for_dbfield*, но для конкретного объекта, а надо для всех...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**РЕШЕНИЕ**

В списке отображаемых полей нужно добавить поле которое нам требуется, например *new_filed*

**ADMIN.PY**

```
list_display: Sequence[str] = (
        'get_new_filed_foo',
        )
```

Далее используем декоратор @admin с помощью которого указываем что результат функции будет отображен как поле.

```
@admin.display(description='Название для нового столбца')
def get_new_filed_foo(self, obj: model) -> str:
    result = 2+2
    return f'{result}'
```

Теперь в списке всех объектов для каждого объекта появится еще один столбец с названием "Название для нового столбца", и для каждой троки в этом стобце будет отображаться результат "get_new_filed_foo"